# Ag-Grid detail (child) grids not getting exported

Tags: ag-grid

I'm facing an issue where exporting a grid from Ag-Grid only export details of the master grid, the child grid is not exported. Here's a plunkr showing the issue:

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/jVcvWDJ1NKPSepuS

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to get the child tables to export with the main table data. Is this even a feature of Ag-Grid?

Comment: Note: getNodeChildDetails in the plunkr .html is deprecated as of version 24.  The answers below do not address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is the default behavior of ag-grid to *not* export the detail grids of a master detail grid. The good news: it is totally possible to export the data in detail grids. The bad news: it's just a little complicated. There isn't a simple setting you can do like `exportDetailGrids = true`. Here is the official documentation on how to do it https://ag-grid.com/angular-grid/excel-export-master-detail/

I will show the basics of how to do it here though (in Angular), along with a bonus not detailed in the documentation. You have to put a property in the HTML like this:

```
[defaultExportParams]="defaultExportParams"
```

Then add the property in your .ts file:

```
private defaultExportParams;
```

You can define `defaultExportParams` in the constructor in the same file:

```
this.defaultExportParams = {
  getCustomContentBelowRow: function (params) {
    return [
      [
        //column header names
        cell(''),
        cell('Call Id', 'header'),
        cell('Direction', 'header'),
        cell('Number', 'header')
      ],
    ].concat(
      params.node.data.callRecords.map(function (record) {
        //values from data
        return [
          cell(''),
          cell(record.callId, 'body'),
          cell(record.direction, 'body'),
          cell(record.number, 'body')
        ];
      }),
      [[]]
    );
  },
  columnWidth: 120 //this is important
};
```

Here is the cell function:

```
function cell(text, styleId) {
    return {
        styleId: styleId,
        data: {
            type: /^\d+$/.test(text) ? 'Number' : 'String',
            value: String(text),
        },
    };
}
```

If your details grids all have the same column structure than you can do it like shown above. If your detail grids have different column structures you can use a decision structure (this is not mentioned in the documentation):

```
this.defaultExportParams = {
    getCustomContentBelowRow: function (params) {
        if (params.node.data.Group == 'Detail Grid One') {
            //set column titles and data here for detail grid 1
        } else {
            //set column titles and data here for detail grid 2
        },

        columnWidth: 120
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's possible via creating own `processCellCallback` for that:

[ag-grid export doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/)

```
params.processCellCallback = (params)=>{ 
    //here as params you will get references to api (parent grid api), columnApi, node
    //you can use node as a target and then request needed data via childApi
    ...
    return "your string result";
  };
```

But I'm not sure how exactly child dependency should be presented on `csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this Via XLSX library. Below is the code I achieved this.

let rows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();

```
let sr_array = [[your column headers for Master Data]];
let task_array = [[your column header for Detail Data]];

rows.forEach(function (rowdata, index) {
  var sr = rowdata.data;
  sr_array.push([your master data attributes]);
  rowdata.setExpanded(true);
});

this.gridOptions.api.forEachDetailGridInfo(function (detailGridInfo) {
  detailGridInfo.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
    let task = node.data;
    task_array.push([Your detail data attributes]);
  });
});

const ws_sr: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(sr_array);
const ws_task: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(task_array);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws_sr, 'Master Data');
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws_task, 'Detail Data');
XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'export.xlsx');



rows.forEach(function (rowdata, index) {
  var sr = rowdata.id;
  rowdata.setExpanded(false);
});
```